# Suggested edit accepted and later rejected

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, activity-summary

What happens when the previously accepted suggested edit gets rejected? And how do I know it was rejected? I couldn't find any info neither in the *reputation* tab nor in the *activity* tab, I can only see that the reputation dropped by 2, but no notification or trace similar to *unupvote*. Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *cannot* be rejected later. Once accepted, a suggested edit *stays* accepted.

Most likely the post you suggested an edit for was *deleted* instead. Check the `show removed post` checkbox at the bottom of your reputation tab to see if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Thanks for explanation.